# DeleteOnExit jvm shutdown

Tags: java, spring, jvm

I currently have a tomcat webapp that needs files deleted when the JVM is being shutdown.  I created a custom ContextLoaderListener to handle the contextDestroyed event.  Inside of here I call deleteOnExit on the appropriate files.  However, ever since jdk 1.6.0_14 I am unable to deleteOnExit.  Googling indicates that there was a change that is somewhat expected, but I haven't seen a work around for this.  Anyone have any ideas?

Below code does NOT work.

```
for(File f : myFileList)
try{
    f.deleteOnExit()
} finally {
    f.delete()
}
```

Comment: Is this happening regardless of normal termination of the virtual machine? Also, make sure that you close all handles on the file as well.

Comment: Note that `File.deleteOnExit` would generally be invoked when you create a file, rather than in a shutdown handler. The point is, you request the file be deleted when system exits (in orderly fashion).

Comment: deleteOnExit is bad, leaks and may delete even a different file than you expect. In short: do not use it. (and the `finally` part is plenty to delete the file, you won't get much better results)

Comment: I ended up changing where the delete was called and got that to work.

Comment: if you're deleting on start up now, then would you accept the answer below? if not, then where did you move your delete code? this info might help others later.

Comment: The below answer was not helpful in my solution.  I am calling it using an API remove method for the class I'm using.  Its still not working perfectly, and it isn't really applicable to abstract file deletion.  But the temp files are at least getting cleaned up.

Comment: Bestsss gave the correct 'answer', even though it was comment formed.  Using processExplorer by microsoft I was able to see that the files had multiple handles on them, even though I only expected one.  So when I closed the expected handle, calling delete() wouldn't succeed.

Comment: 1. You are calling things in the wrong order, you first try to delete, and if you fail you can deleteOnExit, not the other way around 2. Delete the files on startup is a much cleaner method, you can run it on a separate thread for example. You can attempt to delete on close, but if you care about cleanup you should really also do it at startup OR spin up another process after the JVM died to do the cleanup. 3. If your files are well ordered, you can just delete the folder instead of trying to clear file by file

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you're going to be happy with the results of cleaning up files as part of an orderly shutdown process. For example, if your process crashes or is stopped with "kill -9", then your cleanup code will not run.

A more reliable approach is to set up the environment during start up / initialization. If you segregate the files for this application in a specific directory, then this is easy: just [empty the directory](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0483.html) in question.

Exactly where the "empty directory" call belongs, depends on your application. For example, if you wrote a servlet, then use [the init method](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29). Or, if you use Spring, then they provide various initialization hooks such as an [init-method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html).

Comment: When do you propose emptying the directory in question?  Also, what method do you propose for emptying the directory?  They are already segregated into their own directory.  If our process crashes or a kill -9 is called, going to a directory and emptying it out is the least of our worries.  In normal day to day operations, we may deploy code 4-5 times in our Dev environment, so it gets to be a real hassle without the appropriate clean up steps.

Comment: I would empty the directory on startup, as you initialize the resource that writes the files. Hooking into startup is going to be very reliable, hooking into shutdown is inherently unreliable.